# Single HTML content source for div on multiple pages

Tags: jquery, html

Can you please describe what I should start trying or researching for this problem please?

What I want to do is to be able to have a single source for a `<div>` content, but be able to use that tag on other pages. That way I only have to update one source and it will be the same on every single page.

To add context: think of a work "transfer guide" a menu that shows my workers what department does what, their hours of operation, and phone and fax numbers. I've added this part to a side slide-in panel menu with screen overlay so that my workers can open it no matter what they're looking at.

The problem is that I will eventually have hundreds of pages. We will be working with user guides, SOP, and procedure pages. I don't want to have to "hard code" the contents of the transfer guide in every single page. That will become a nightmare when I have to inevitably update a piece of information like a phone extension or fax number.

I, of course don't mind doing the leg work online, I just don't know what to start looking at. I'm fairly good a jquery, but even the name of  what I'm looking for would help get started in researching.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Partial view can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for following 2 things and refactor javascript for different functions in external js file.

```
<div id='your_div'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('your_div').load('html_file.html'); 
</script>
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

and

```
<iframe src="html_file.html"></iframe>
```

iframe should be less preferred.

Comment: Thanks @Amit, and how would I reference the .html file location? Just like any other URL? Like if that .html is located in a separate folder can I just do: `$('your_div').load('..folder/folder/html_file.html');` ? Also, how would I structure that file if all I need is just text, is it like a regular HTML page?

Comment: not the double dot syntax. But folder can be specified like $( "#new-projects" ).load( "/resources/load.html #projects li" ); 
   See examples on http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: The iframe works, but the jquery does not. This is what I tried: the HTML `<div id="transferguide"></div>` and the jquery is in a document ready section `$('#transferguide').load('shared/TransferGuide.html');` the Transfer Guide is in one folder called "shared". Why is the iframe less desirable or less preferred?

Comment: iframe is less desirable because it loads a page within a page. If you load a iframe with in a page, check the F12 chrome developer tab of Network. These are 2 different pages loaded into one. http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/06/03/using-iframes-sparingly/                     Also, try calling div.load from inside a button click or document.ready. Hopefully, you have jquery file included and there are no errors on the console.

Comment: I put it in a document.ready section (checked with a console.log) but it's not loading the contents. I also tried it on the button click to open the side panel. Thanks for the suggestion, I'm going to play around with it for a bit.

Comment: so I found an error in the console, but I'm not sure what it means - "Cannot load "file name" (path is correct). Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https." - Any ideas?

Comment: So I figured out the issue. I was running the whole thing off my flash drive, I guess the issue is that the .load requires a server side. I loaded it up on my server and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

1. It has informaiton stored in `<div>` tags and will not be displayed initially.
2. On click of links in left navigation, the `div` will be loaded into right panel.
3. I am not using `<iframe>` as it's sometimes unreliable and will be overdo in tihs case.
4. Here, you need to change only `div` content in one place everywhere it will reflect same.

**Content of my .html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">



    function loadContent(selector){
            //$("#loadOnClick").html($(selector).html());

            $("#loadOnClick").load("resources/load.html div"+selector);
        };


    $(document).ready(function(){

        loadContent("#userGuide");

    });
</script>
<style>
div.container11 {
    width: 100%;

}
section.container1{
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    display: flex;
}

.displayInline{
    -webkit-flex: 1;  /* Safari 6.1+ */
    -ms-flex: 1;  /* IE 10 */    
    flex: auto;
}

header, footer {
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: powderblue;
    clear: left;
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    border-right: 2px solid gray;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

nav ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 30px;
}

div#loadOnClick {
    float: right;
}

 .displayOnClick1{
    display: none;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<header>
   <h1>Sample: Transfer guide</h1>
</header>

 <section id="container1">
    <nav class="displayInLine" style="width: 20%; float: left;">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#userGuide" class="quickLinks" onclick='loadContent("#userGuide")'>User Guide</a></li>
        <li><a href="#SOP" class="quickLinks" onclick='loadContent("#SOP")'>SOP</a></li>
        <li><a href="#procedurePages" class="quickLinks" onclick='loadContent("#procedurePages")'>Procedure pages</a></li>
        <li><a href="#departmentInformation" class="quickLinks" onclick='loadContent("#departmentInformation")'>Department information</a></li>
        <li><a href="#hoursOfOperations" class="quickLinks" onclick='loadContent("#hoursOfOperations")'>Hours of operations</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="displayInLine" id="loadOnClick" style="width:75%; float: right;">

    </div>
</section>

<footer>Copyright &copy; Om Sao</footer>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Content of `resources/load.html`**

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="userGuide" class="displayOnClick">
    <h1>User Guide</h1>
    <p>This is the userguide for employees</p>
</div>

<div id="SOP" class="displayOnClick">
    <h1>SOP</h1>
    <p>This is the Statement of purpose for employees</p>
</div>

<div id="procedurePages" class="displayOnClick">
    <h1>Procedure pages</h1>
    <p>This is the Procedure pages for employees</p>
</div>

<div id="departmentInformation" class="displayOnClick">
    <h1>Department information</h1>
    <p>This is the Department information for employees</p>
</div>

<div id="hoursOfOperations" class="displayOnClick">
    <h1>Hours of operations</h1>
    <p>This is the Hours of operations for employees</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks OmSao, but I was thinking more a long the lines of having like a section that I can add to every different page, but the contents are only in one spot. So if I need to update the contents I don't have to do it on every page, just the one section.

Comment: @Chester: Did you get answer so far ? Please check my edited answer now.
If it satisfies your requirement. Then, close the question by Accepting/Upvoting answer.

Thanks

Comment: your idea is closer, but I don't need a click event. I tried to modify your code a bit for a straight up load, but I can't get it to work for some reason. So I already have the site build and I have a sliding panel, where I want the content to be in. @Amit 's ifram idea did work `<iframe src="html_file.html"></iframe>` but did say that it's the less preferred method for some reason. What I did: `<div id="transferguide"></div>` in the HTML. Then I put `$('#transferguide').load('shared/TransferGuide.html');` in a document ready section.